# Azure DevOps removed sha1 support

Tags: git, azure, rsa, openssh, ssh-keygen

Reading at the release notes for OpenSSH 8.2,
https://www.openssh.com/txt/release-8.2
,
rsa1 is now deprecated and considered broken. So Microsoft decided that their systems should no longer support it (I suppose that makes sense). However, they still don't support ecdsa or ed25519.

It is possible to reenable rsa 1 by inserting this in `/home/<user>/.ssh/config`: (as stated in Microsoft forum here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/923455/cannot-interact-with-git-repos-with-openssh-82.html )

```
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
```

So how does one create a secure authentication to Azure DevOps?

Comment: For some reason you are mixing up SHA-1 and RSA. Can't you use SHA-2 and RSA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure DevOps does not currently support any secure method of connecting over SSH.

The group 14 with SHA-1 is 2048 bits in size and is at the lower end of acceptable strength (112-bit equivalent).  In this case, SHA-1 is used not for signatures, but as a PRF for generating key data.  This isn't insecure, although of course using a non-SHA-1 algorithm would be better.  Group 1 is too weak to be secure.

However, Azure DevOps lacks support for anything but RSA with SHA-1, and that's definitely insecure.  RSA with SHA-2 isn't possible because Azure DevOps doesn't negotiate the extensions necessary to use SHA-2, and there are no other key types supported.

Your best bet is to use HTTPS for access to Azure DevOps, or move to a more secure platform.  Note, however, that you may want to force TLS 1.2 because Azure DevOps supports TLS 1.0 and 1.1, both of which are considered insecure and [deprecated](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-oldversions-deprecate-06).  You can do so by setting `http.https://dev.azure.com.sslVersion` to `tlsv1.2`.

Comment: If you do not want to limit the TLS version setting to Azure DevOps Services (e.g. when you're using Azure DevOps Server, too, or any other repository that may offer lower TLS versions), set `http.sslVersion` itself: `git config --global http.sslVersion tlsv1.2`

Comment: Also, a docs link for the setting might be helpful. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpsslVersion

Answer (score 1):

As of yesterday a fix has rolled out to Azure DevOps with a `sha256` option (`diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256`) alongside `sha1` and that has resolved the issue:

```
$ GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv" git pull
...
debug2: KEX algorithms: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
...
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
```